# Find and replace the last instance of a substring in a string using PHP

Tags: php

I have a dynamic list of sports. Each sport ends with a `,`. The last `,` is removed using `$sports = substr($sports, 0, -2);`. Now I'm trying to figure out how to replace the last `,` (comma space) with `, and` (comma and space). I may have missed it, but I don't see a function for this. Is there one or another creative way for accomplishing it?

**Original List**

```
Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf,
```

**Desired List**

```
Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, and Golf
```

Comment: If you have original data as array look at this: https://pastebin.com/SLUUdECM

Comment: @Mr.B: Hi, you can consider my updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48932774/2915423 . The solution is far simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use advantage of `explode()`/`implode()` to perform this. Check the [live example here](https://repl.it/repls/ActualReflectingRuntimelibrary).

```
$list = 'Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf, ';

function display( $string ) {
  // Splitting the list by comma
  $str = explode(',', $string);

  // Removing empty items
  $str = array_filter($str, function($item) {
    return strlen(trim($item)) > 0;
  });

  // prepeding "and" before the last item only if it contains more than one item
  $size = count($str);

  if( $size > 1 ) {
    $str[$size - 1] = "and " . (string) $str[$size - 1];
  }

  // Make list great (string) again
  $str = implode(', ', $str);  

  return $str;
}


echo display($list);
```

Will echo :

> Football,  Soccer,  Basketball,  Swimming,  Baseball, and Golf

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = substr("Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf, ", 0, -2);

$last_comma_position = strrpos($str, ',');

if($last_comma_position != false)
{
    echo substr_replace($str, ' and', $last_comma_position, 1);
}
```

http://php.net/substr_replace

Or as a function

```
function replace_last($haystack, $needle, $replaceWith)
{
    $last_position = strrpos($haystack, $needle);

    if($last_position != false)
    {
        return substr_replace($haystack, $replaceWith, $last_position, strlen($needle));
    }
}

$str = substr("Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf, ", 0, -2);

echo replace_last($str, ',', ' and');
```

Both print out

```
Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball and Golf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try you own method. Somethign like this:

```
$string = "Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf,"; 

function addAndToList($string) {

$string = substr($string, 0, -1);
$stringArray = explode(',', $string); 

$resultString = ''; 
foreach ($stringArray as $index => $val) {
  if (!isset($stringArray[$index+1])) 
       $resultString .= 'and '.$val; 
  else 
      $resultString .= $val.', ';
}

return $resultString; 
}

echo addAndToList($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

- match last word of the string
- delimited by a space character
- while storing it into the back reference pseudo-variable `$1`
- add the desired string

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$sports = "Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, Golf, ";
$sports = substr($sports, 0, -2);

echo preg_replace('/ ([a-zA-Z]+)$/', ' and $1', $sports) . "\n";
```

This snippets outputs:

```
Football, Soccer, Basketball, Swimming, Baseball, and Golf
```

The solution can be verified in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/Ui5fC).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your variable is already defined:

```php
$arr = array_reverse(explode(', ', $sports));
$last = array_shift($arr);
$arr[0] .= " and {$last}";
$sports = implode(', ', array_reverse($arr));
echo "$sports\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting my initial solution:-)